# How to restore the Unity greeter after installing and uninstalling xfce-desktop?

Tags: lightdm

After installing the `xfce-desktop` package, the `lightdm` greeter runs instead of the `unity` one, even after uninstalling it. I've looked in every `lightdm` conf file, and greeter-session is unity-greeter. If I Symlink `/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter` to unity-greeter, it works. However, if I remove `/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter`, no greeter shows. What's going on?

Comment: Do you mean you've installed `xubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: I did, but then I uninstalled it.

Comment: Execute this "sudo apt-get remove xubuntu-desktop --purge && sudo apt-get install unity-greeter"

Answer (score 0):

execute this command in terminal and choose your required greeter (display manager) :

```
sudo dpkg-configure lightdm
```

if it doesn't work try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: No, lightdm-gtk-greeter is still showing up. I'd expect that to work, and I tried it, but it doesn't do anything.